# Ruby on Rails - Email confirmation link gives nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, email-validation

I want an email to be sent when a user registers. This email should contain a link **that changes the account to a full user**. I want this email link to be a token for security.

- email_token  is a random generated token per user
- email_activation_token  is a boolean saying if the user completed registration or not

**Currently**: I get the email to send but when I click the link I get this error.

### NoMethodError in UsersController#accept_invitation

```
undefined method `email_activation_token=' for nil:NilClass
```

**Link Sent** `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation.tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ`

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end

  def accept_invitation
      @user = User.find_by_email_token(params[:email_token])
      @user.email_activation_token = true
      @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
  end
  end
end
```

**registration_confirmation.html.haml**

```
Confirm your email address please!

= accept_invitation_users_url(@user.email_token)
```

**user.rb model**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
      before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
      before_create { generate_token(:email_token) }

      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, :on => :create, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

end
```

**email_activations_controller.rb**

```
class EmailActivationsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @user = User.find_by_email_activation_token!(params[:email_token])
        @user.email_activation_token = true
        @user.save!
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
    end
    def new
        @user = User.find_by_email_activation_token!(params[:email_token])
    end

    def edit
    end
end
```

Comment: what does your routes.rb file look like for the email_activation resource?  I'm trying to do the same thing, and I'm really close to following your approach, but I can't get this to work out right.  Can you help?   thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick stab at it:

`= accept_invitation_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token)`

The link `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation.tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ` is wrong.

It should look something like `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation?email_token=tLPOjM3hdA13rEv5FNhsOQ` in order to be part of the `params` hash.

Comment: how do you generate that url?  I took a stab at it and I have `resources :users { resources :verify_emails }` which gives me a helper named `edit_user_verify_email_url`, but I have to pass in the whole user object as a parameter instead of just the email token.  I get an error that says "No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"verify_emails", :user_id=>#<User id: 116...".  Could you help me?